# How to read parameter passed from asp.net page, using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

I'm new to ASP.net, how can I read parameters passed from ASP.net page (http://website.com/index.aspx?id=12&nam=eee).

Any small example will be appreciated, just something for me to start from.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using your sample URL:

```
string id = Request.QueryString["id"];

string nam = Request.QueryString["nam"];
```

Read about [Request.QueryString on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx). You probably want to convert the `id` value to an int.

Answer (score 3):

For security reasons, be careful with XSS attacks. Please use this library:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx

Example:

```
String Name = AntiXss.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString["Name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

They are available in `Request.QueryString`.  This is a collection of string key/value pairs, that can also be accessed by ordinal index.

Comment: Thanks,
But what I was looking for is small code example in C#

Answer (score 0):

```
string st1=Request.QueryString["t1"].ToString();
string st1=Request.QueryString["t1"].ToString();
int a=Convert.ToInt32(st1)+Convert.ToInt32(st2);
Response.Write(a);
```

Comment: Its better when you write a short description ;)