# Fetch User ID / username from URL to display contents on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read parameter passed from asp.net page, using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078171/how-to-read-parameter-passed-from-asp-net-page-using-c)

I want to display profile contents on a ASP.NET web page based on the user id which is displayed at the end of a the URL, as in a facebook page.

I want to be able to derive the id from the URL just so I can search the database to match the Id.

If someone could help me derive the Id which is the last bit of the URL, I could convert that to a string and do the rest.
Help on this is  much appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593709/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-c-sharp

Comment: Could you provide the sample url??

Comment: Just be wary of not allowing users who shouldn't be able to see users be able to access this directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on how you're programming and the structure of your URL.

Example;
If the URL is something similar to http://mydomain.com/page.aspx?id=1 you can read the querystring by doing the following.

```
strID = Request.QueryString("ID");
```

In this instance the value of strID would be 1.

Are you using URL rewrite modules or simple Web Forms?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the name of the current page try:

```
Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

My addition to the already solution:

```
 string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

This code will give you the URL but storing UserId and sensitive data in url is not good practice. My Advice will be to use Encoding techniques with query string.